# how do I access the object the object i sent to the server file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

//Sent an ajax http post request to a php file on the server, the post //request is a simple object.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var person = {
    "firstName" : "Adebowale",
    "lastName" : "Johnson",
    "ago" : 43
}

xhr.open("POST","phfile.php",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-     urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if((status >= 200) && (status < 300) || (status === 304)) {

            alert(xhr.responseText);

        }
    }
};

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(person));
```

//if I do alert(xhr.responseText);
//I get object{} from the browser.

//On the server, using php, how do I access the object, if I do echo or //print_r, I get the empty object --- object{} with none of the properties.

//As you can tell from the tone of my question, am still very new to all //these, am just trying to learn please.

//on my phfile.php, I set up the following php code...

```
<?php

print_r 
//How do I access the object I sent to this file please
?>
```

Comment: We need to see your "ajax http post request" and your "php file on the server". Click "edit" under your question and add the code.

Comment: you sent a raw json string, you'll probably have to read it from `php://input`.

Comment: hi, I've added the original ajax http post request as adviced, hope you guys can find time to take a lood at it please. Am still stuck. Can't accet the object I sent on the server.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the parameters as JSON instead of the normal URL-encoded data? Then you could use `$_POST` to read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read raw POST data using `STDIN`:

```
$post_data = fopen("php://input", "r");
$json = fgets($post_data);
$object = json_decode($json);
$firstName = $object->firstName;
$lastName = $object->lastName;
$age = $object->age;
```

You could simplify all of this by just passing the data as URL-encoded form fields:

```
xhr.send('firstName=' + encodeURIComponent(person.firstName) + '&lastName=' + encodeURIComponent(person.lastName) + '&ago=' + encodeURIComponent(person.ago);
```

Then you can just access them as `$_POST['firstName']`, etc. in PHP.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, but i did not send the object in a file, it is appended directly to the ajax http post request. I've editted the original question by adding my entire code. Please take a look;

Comment: There's no file in my answer.

Comment: yeah i know, I was only thinking fgets() method reads off a file. In any case got error message - Use of undefined constant STDIN. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that STDIN is only available when running from CLI, not webserver. I've revised to use `php://input`

Comment: Cheers Barmar, but unfortunately, still came up with Notice:Trying to get the property of a non-object...

Comment: Thanks Barman, particularly for your patience with me. The fopen("php://input", "r") method has worked fine. And so has the encondeuricomponent method. I don't know what I was doing wrong the other time. But its all cool now. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont see the need for `JSON.stringify(person)` in your `AJAX` request, since all the `keys` of the `Object` are already in `strings`.

Since you are using `POST` method, you can directly access the object like

```
print_r ($_POST['person']);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the  response, but am still getting an "undefined index: person..." error on the php file when I do  print_r ($_POST['person']);

Comment: remove this line ==> xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-     urlencoded");