# Parse JSON from the body of the POST

Tags: javascript, json, post

I'm using cameratag.com to record video on my website. The service can send a  JSON response to my server so I can save the data to my database. However I don't know how to proceed here:

The documentation states *Please note that the JSON repsonse is passed in the body of the POST and not as form parameters. Here is an example of how you would parse the response in ruby:*

```
data = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)
video_uuid = data["uuid"]
```

But I don't know how to get the data on JavaScript.

POST sample:

```
    {
  "uuid": "00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4",
  "camera_uuid": "98373a20-79ee-0130-3e42-1231390fcc11",
  "created_at": "2013-12-20T05:25:02.000Z",
  "percent_complete": 100,
  "short_code": "KKtB4Q",
  "metadata": {
  },
  "state": "published",
  "recorded_from": "http://singwho.com",
  "publish_type": null,
  "formats": [
    {
      "name": "720p",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720,
      "video_url": "https://cameratag.com/videos/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4/720p/mp4.mp4",
      "flv_url": null,
      "flv_stream": null,
      "mp4_url": "https://cameratag.com/videos/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4/720p/mp4.mp4",
      "mp4_stream": "rtmp://sa0xpxq1vz1ri.cloudfront.net/cfx/st&mp4:98373a20-79ee-0130-3e42-1231390fcc11/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4_720p.mp4?Expires=1436892019&Signature=OhVUCK0GGLSNiaO~2MVp03YPmb9xcYQnbKMFfRaZsVwerQtdwF9Kcf~fKyg1vQH9HYZdoeADXmszRxpxi2Np6FH8YloVFjPFjOkBPJEQ0Z4IWh6hKbWD8hL861kSFKKrEBNgxSJeTG1F8XpXMISRTYhZ11G3FRoZwg42CwKIP0w0LqQnIwz5Hi0yw35AgQRn1zBBEYqBBkR~QhW9OyLkU5K15b0-RnOH~EmDXUzGJQHBkGgSyCXY0D41Ak~~Co0ocqJD9Phe2ZfA7Qy-JHWwLHr66bQuP3g~E3CgGo0-vtCphnWrxDTxgNezP~SRI~BWrvlljVwPWF5LZXy5ByTf1w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIYEVFIMHKY7YWGKA",
      "webm_url": "https://cameratag.com/videos/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4/720p/webm.webm",
      "webm_stream": "rtmp://sa0xpxq1vz1ri.cloudfront.net/cfx/st&webm:98373a20-79ee-0130-3e42-1231390fcc11/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4_720p.webm?Expires=1436892019&Signature=PDL1Bubk6QkW-kNRm9GhHFAxdNdA57S6S0YM1hgM5SuHYULS84dOXcYz~LjPFd-bjgOJDWdEONfv60SqcFkN0cy93BHbs1Pk3bNLW-y0VFnMzIuT8QmEWuO60Yt8Bg7IJdvtph3Jmtolay9VFL~ZPTcX1ljhPKbBiZzIhuzfMtBChQrGXAb19jG6Rv8bxrST8aR~EuC31XFQ4LlN-L8G~pkf9s-DOquNvYUnkv-0hIyiDHG4gZZKurNYyz8ZVZRh0ZKTby2C~dDIiaKskthVsmfnRIa9ADFwywDCcI7y5nUN6yVpISuRpYqoUmpbFiI3Df84ZYyXaa6vhfQu1U3CGw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIYEVFIMHKY7YWGKA",
      "thumbnail_url": "https://cameratag.com/videos/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4/720p/thumb.png",
      "small_thumbnail_url": "https://cameratag.com/videos/00012710-4b65-0131-ffe6-22000a499ea4/720p/small_thumb.png",
      "state": "COMPLETED",
      "completed_at": "2013-12-20T05:30:12.000Z",
      "length": 195
    }
  ],
  "plays": 0
}
```

Comment: It would be sending a JSON string in the response to Ajax Post call. You can do JSON.parse(response) in the callback function to get the JSON/Javascript Object.

Comment: Can you provide an example API URL or provide the JSON response?

Comment: This is not a response to AJAX or any other _request_. The OP is referring to the [Server Callback](http://cameratag.com/docs/app_advanced#callback) feature provided by CameraTag. A user of that feature of the service is supposed to build a page on their own web server which can receive POST requests that contain JSON in the body. Having done so, the user will configure the server callback feature "_(found on your CameraTag's setup tab)_" with the URL of that new page. Then, each time a video is processed by the service for the user, the service will POST JSON about the video to the page.

Comment: So the answer is that you can't do this in Javascript in the browser, you need a server.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193733/how-do-i-access-the-object-the-object-i-sent-to-the-server-file/31194078#31194078) shows how to do it in PHP.